# wp_delete_attachment not working with multiple values

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, html

input with attachment image id not working anyone known can tell where is the problem

```
<input type="hidden" name="jfiler-items-exclude-imgid" value="["4602","4603"]">
    if (isset($_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'])) {
        $att_ids = $_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'];
        $att_id = explode(',', $att_ids);
        foreach ($att_id as $atts_id){
            wp_delete_attachment($att_ids);
    }
```

Comment: The value of your input is going to be `[`. You can't nest double quotes inside of double quotes.

Comment: @Jrod Okay but I',m using  [link](https://github.com/avral/jquery.filer) this input coming from Jquery/JavaScript is there have any other way to change quotes

Comment: Use `.toString` on your array before setting it as the value of your input. This will turn your array into a comma separated string.

Comment: @Jrod this  jquery-file-min library and this is too big you recommend me to add .toString to in this library

Comment: Please show me the javascript/jquery you are using to set the value of your input.

Comment: i try this 
  if (isset($_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'])) {
   $att_ids = explode(',', $_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid']);
   print_r($att_ids);
   foreach($att_ids as $key=>$att_id){
     wp_delete_attachment($att_id);
    }
  }
but receiving this array Array ( [0] => [\"4602\" [1] => \"4603\"] )

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve thankyou @Jrod You'r right

```
if (isset($_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid'])) {
    $string = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['jfiler-items-exclude-imgid']);
    $string1 = str_replace('\\', '', $string); 
    $string3 = str_replace('[', '', $string1);
    $string4 = str_replace(']', '', $string3);
    $att_ids = explode(',', $string4);
    foreach($att_ids as $key=>$att_id){
            wp_delete_attachment($att_id);
        }
}
```